# Translation help from idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, internationalization, android-studio

I have a android project which has two string files English and Italic.  the Italic file was  perfectly translated from the English file. Recently I have added many new string to the English file. But it is too plenty to manage which is missing in Italic file. Is there support for that from any of IDEs like "Android Studio" or "intellij Idea".

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Plugin for Android has that feature, if you open the `Lint Warnings` view it will show which strings are missing from which locale resources under the category "Correctness:Messages".

Comment: Any suggestions how to do it? I do have a eclipse, but not experienced with it at all.

Comment: How to do what exactly? Just open your Android project with eclipse, then activate the Lint Warnings view (Window->Show view->Other...). If it's not showing up already, click the refresh button.

Comment: Doesn't it shows if default translation is missing string which is in foreign translation, but if default has, but foreign does not The tool gives nothing. I see lots of "Lint" output not the one I need.

Comment: Mmmm I didn't think of that. You can always swap them, then swap them back once you're finished.

Comment: actually lint options has checkbox for missing translations and extra translations. You are right! Just need to figure out how to use the tool. Still I will wait with accepting the answer because someone may come with more straight forward idea.